# Know finish of thread objective c

Tags: ios, arrays, multithreading

I have some line of code like:

```
while( condition ) {
  // do stuff
  [self lauchProcess:parameter];
}

-(void)launchProcess:(id)par{
  // do stuff
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
    // do stuff
  });
}
```

So I launch a lot of background processes.
I would like to know when all processes are finished to do somethings else.
How can I do?

Comment: I think if you want to know when a thread is finished you should run `dispatch_sync` instead of `dispatch_async`. But this way in your code you lost the ability to dispatch multiple ones at the same time.

Comment: Look at docs for dispatch_group_enter and dispatch_group_leave.

Answer (score 0):

Use **`dispatch_get_main_queue()`** inside of your dispatch_get_global_queue().

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
            //  Background work
                 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    //This block will execute other stuffs Once background task is completed do your other stuff
    }); });
```

- `dispatch_get_main_queue()`  executes tasks on the application’s main thread.

> It is usually called from a background queue when some background
>   processing has finished and the user interface needs to be updated.

- `dispatch_get_global_queue()` is concurrent queues (background threads) and from the main
  page for global queues.

  The global concurrent queues represent three priority bands

  > ```
  >     DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH
  >     DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT
  >     DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW
  > ```

As @Philip says you need to take a view about [dispatch groups](http://commandshift.co.uk/blog/2014/03/19/using-dispatch-groups-to-wait-for-multiple-web-services/)